# Can I replace “from which” in this sentence by “where”

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, relative-adverbs

I have the original sentences:

> We climbed to the top of the tower. We had a beautiful view from there.

We have been instructed to rewrite the above sentences using relative pronoun/relative adverb. And the answers are:

> (1) We climbed to the top tower which we had a beautiful view from.

> (2) We climbed to the top tower from which we had a beautiful view.

I wonder if I could use relative adverb “where” to rewrite the sentence like this:

> We climbed to the top of tower where we had a beautiful view.

Comment: Hi. Which one do you think is the correct answer?

Comment: As @Billy Kerr asks, what choices do you think are valid? And why?  Also (here’s a hint for another approach): Don’t feel straitjacketed by the original passage’s order. How might you come up with a valid answer in which “We had a wonderful view” is the main clause?

Comment: No: You need _We climbed to the top tower from where we had a beautiful view_.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the words "of the" were accidentally left out.

> We climbed to the top of the tower, which we had a beautiful view from.

I think this is acceptable, but is rather awkward because of the long gap between "which" and "from". Some people (incorrectly, see e.g. [Fowler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_Modern_English_Usage)) believe that it is wrong to end a sentence with a proposition. Probably that is the "mistake" this exercise is supposed to "correct".

> We climbed to the top of the tower, from which we had a beautiful view.

I think this is better style, as it is easier for the reader to understand. You can immediately see what the "from" applies to.

> We climbed to the top of tower, where we had a beautiful view.

This is also fine.

Note that, in all three cases, a comma should be used, since what comes after it is a non-defining relative clause. See [this explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining).